# a diamond dependency problem - upgrade a pandas program to python 3.12. now a lot of things are broken

Tags: pandas, six

Facing this mess:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/Users/kameronacole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 73, in <module>
    from tabula import read_pdf
     File "/Users/kameronacole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages   /tabula/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .io import convert_into, convert_into_by_batch, read_pdf, read_pdf_with_template
    File "/Users/kameronacole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages /tabula/io.py", line 32, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Users/kameronacole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "/Users/kameronacole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas._libs import (
  File "/Users/kameronacole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
  File "interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
  File "hashtable.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.hashtable
  File "missing.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.missing
  File "/Users/kameronacole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/_libs/tslibs/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion import localize_pydatetime
  File "conversion.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion
  File "offsets.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets
  File "timestamps.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps
  File "timedeltas.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas
  File "timezones.pyx", line 24, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.timezones
  File "/Users/kameronacole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dateutil/tz/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .tz import *
  File "/Users/kameronacole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py", line 21, in <module>
    from six.moves import _thread
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'
```

Not sure where to begin. This is the code block from line 21 to line 73:

```
import PyPDF2

import textract
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

filename = 'Dog_Breed.pdf'  # open allows you to read the file.pdfFileObj = open(filename,'rb')#The pdfReader variable is a readable object that will be parsed.pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)#Discerning the number of pages will allow us to parse through all the pages.num_pages = pdfReader.numPages

pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdfFileObj)

num_pages = len(pdfReader.pages)
count = 0
text = ""  # The while loop will read each page.
while count < num_pages:
    pageObj = pdfReader.pages[count]
    count += 1
    text += pageObj.extract_text()  # This if statement exists to check if the above library returned words. It's done because PyPDF2 cannot read scanned files.
if text != "":
    text = text

# If the above returns as False, we run the OCR library textract to #convert scanned/image based PDF files into text.else:
#  text = textract.process(fileurl, method='tesseract', language='eng')
print('')
print('Printing the whole pdf. Tabular format not retained with this method')
print('')
print(text)
print('')

#################################################################################################################
#                                                                                                               #
# Now we use tabula package to convert the pdf to csv.  This retains the format, somewhat, but the reason for   #
# using it is because the standard python pdf packages don't do what I want (not because I really want a csv    #
#################################################################################################################


from tabula import read_pdf

# reads table from pdf file

df = read_pdf("Dog_Breed.pdf", pages=1)[0]
df.to_csv('Dog_Breed.csv')

print('printing the rows from the csv')
print()
```

All this worked in a previous python version - can't recall which.  I had to get a new Mac, and re-install PyCharm. The old machine was erased.  I still can't imagine that python is still so immature that it produces these errors with no hope of resolution - all because of packaging (dependency) inconsistencies. Reminds me of Java, like, 40 years ago.

I could guess.  What was last year's version of python?  assuming if I just switch to that interpreter, my code will work.

I see the stackoverflow suggestions all point to "no module pandas found".  That is not my issue.  I have all modules,including the correct version of six (there is a dependency between six 1.12.0 and textract - can't use 1.16

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question to make it clear, that this is a diamond dependency problem? I believe mentioning imports is just enough, but requirements conflict is missing. Did you also check for the forks of `textract` - there are plenty of them, including [textract-py3](https://pypi.org/project/textract-py3/), which claims to have the `six` dependency fixed.

Comment: ok, I can add "diamond dependency problem" - but I'm not entirely sure that this is the case - while indeed there is the textract/six dependency, I fixed that already (I think) by following the warning, which said to use the earlier version of textract. But there are more anomalies - for example, many of my import statements are marked as unused. But this cannot be true -  seems like it's just ignoring any code after the initial failure.  I will try textract-py3 to see if it helps.  thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle diamond dependency in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77939981/how-to-handle-diamond-dependency-in-python)