# How to handle diamond dependency in Python?

Tags: python, dependency-management

My project has two dependencies, and each of them transitively depends on a different major version of protobuf.

The general situation is well described

- in an article [Google Best Practices for Java Libraries: What is a diamond dependency conflict?](https://jlbp.dev/what-is-a-diamond-dependency-conflict)
- and also [Software Engineering at Google; Dependency Management: Conflicting Requirements and Diamond Dependencies](https://abseil.io/resources/swe-book/html/ch21.html#conflicting_requirements_and_diamond_de).

The specific problem in my project manifests with this error message from Poetry.

```
kfp (1.8.21) depends on protobuf (>=3.13.0,<4)
and robotframework-browser (18.0.0) depends on protobuf (4.25.1)
```

These packages operate completely independently. They do not share data. If each was able to use its own protobuf version, things would work out. Is this possible in Python?

Comment: In your case: get the newest / a newer version of kfp: the master has `protobuf>=4.21.1,<5` as requirement.

Comment: Can't. The project is a test suite and one thing it tests is KubeFlow Pipelines v1. There `1.8.21` is the latest version of the v1 client library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not easily at all. A single Python environment can't have two copies of a package by the same name.

Your major options are to

1. Find a combination of versions of `kfp` and `robotframework-browser` that have compatible `protobuf` requirements (`kfp~=1.8` is pretty old though, you might consider upgrading!)
2. See if you can force Poetry to install `protobuf~=4` anyway, and see if `kfp` works with it
3. See if you can force Poetry to install `protobuf~=3` anyway, and see if `robotframework-browser` works with it

Beyond that, if you can't upgrade `kfp`, you could fork and patch `kfp` to depend on and use `protobuf>=4`...

Comment: Poetry does not seem to be amendable to dependency overrides, https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/697. As far as I can tell I'd have to manually edit the lock file.